# "Rauswerfen" vs. "Rausschmeißen"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

For example, **rausschmeissen** and **rauswerfen** are used interchangeably in sentences below:

> Der Chef will sie **rausschmeissen**, weil sie ständig zu spät kommt.
>   Der Chef will sie **rauswerfen**, weil sie ständig zu spät kommt.

Is there a situation in which I should pick **rauswerfen** in favour of **rausschmeißen** or vice verse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both words differ only in minimal nuances, so it is rather a question of style or personal preference.
If you use it in the literal meaning of throwing an object, I would pick raus*werfen*, because *werfen* is the normal word for to throw, while *schmeißen* is more colloquial.
However, the use for firing someone from the job is colloquial for both words (the normal word would be *kündigen*, which, btw, takes the person to be fired in dative case instead of accusative), so there is no factual reason to pick one over the other.

Comment: Yes, although I would say that they are both colloquial and should accordingly be avoided when it comes to writing formal texts (CVs etc).

Comment: You can also say "jemanden kündigen", but this seems to be judged as _colloquial_ or _Austrian German_, see DWDS or [here](https://grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?891-Was-ist-grammatikalisch-richtig-die-Nachbarn-sind-gek%FCndigt-worden-oder-den-Nachbarn-ist-gek%FCndigt-worden). So, in the passive voice without agent, you can say "ihm wurde gekündigt" as well as "er wurde gekündigt".

Answer (score 2):

**werfen**

[means](https://www.dwds.de/wb/werfen) *to move something somewhere with momentum (through the air)*: to throw

**schmeißen**

is colloquial and [means](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schmei%C3%9Fen) *to throw sth., often with affect, out of inattention, with momentum, emphasis*

Since *rauswerfen* is already colloquial for [*jemanden entlassen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/entlassen), you can see *rausschmeißen* as a way to stress discontent.

Saying: "Den habe ich rausgeschmissen.", stresses the force that the speaker would have liked to use if he would have literally *kicked them out*.

Saying: "Die haben mich rausgeschmissen.", shows ones discontent about having been treated poorly. If you find your dismissal reasonable, you would rather say: "Die haben mich rausgeworfen." or "Die haben mich entlassen."

Since colloquial speech depends heavily on style and personal preference, please don't take me to court for saying that.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing. Don't bother with the difference, it is almost none. For practical communication it is really no difference.

Comment: Das stimmt, normalerweise bevorzuge ich `rausschmeissen`, weil ich dieses Wort häufiger höre.

Answer (score -2):

compare *di-smiss*, *dis-miss*?

Also cp *Schmiss* "trash, stuff", *Schmeiß-Fliege* "drosophila" (dew lowe, a.k.a. house fly), and [schmieren](https://dwds.de/wb/schmieren), English *to smear*, *smear campaign* "deface, denigrate"; given *dismiss* cp *to mete* and I don't know what; also *niederschmettern*, *to smite*, *abschmettern (of law suits).*

---

Whichever way it went, *rausschmeißen* is chiefly denigrating.

*rauswerfen*, *verwerfen*, etc are not exactly positively connotated, but slightly less derogatory. Perhaps it's distantly relatrd to *rufen*, cp *in Verruf geraten*, opposite of *Beruf* and *guter Ruf*; That is, if the basic root, *weH meant *to turn, change*, the apparent relation to *werfen* and *warp* might be coincidental.

Either invokes the visual metaphor of hurling someone, e.g. out of the saloon.

As in English (e.g. "to let go"), euphemisms are usually sought to maintain politeness, *kündigen*, *etw. entziehen*, *bitten zu gehen*, ...